# Creating files and directories with a certain owner (user/group) while sudoing

Tags: linux, permissions, root, chmod, chown

I need to `wget` something (results in a compressed file in cwd), then I have to extract it, then do some copy/move/modification stuff and perhaps finally execute an script (from the downloaded archive).

Now all these task either directly (`wget`, extract etc.) or indirectly (running the script) result in creating files and directories (all in the current working directory). I do all this stuff as `root` (no way to do it with the final, desired user).

The problem is: Anything created in the process is owned by root or the sudo user. When I'm done (and sometimes in the mid-way), I have to issue a series of `chmod` and `chown` commands to make things right.

Now it would be nice if could somehow tell the system that "From now on, any files or dirs that you create when I issue commands as root, you would create with such and such ownership and permissions".

Answer (score 34):

You can always `sudo -u username touch filename` when your script is executed as `root`. It usually requires no password, depending on your `sudoers` configuration.

Alternatively, run `su username -c touch filename`. The additional arguments are supplied to the user's shell, and the `-c` option to the shell executes the specified commands by convention.

---

Some commands (like `mkdir`) support arguments to specify the permissions:

```
mkdir -m 0700 foo
```

---

By default, file operations respect the `umask` set for the shell. It defines which permissions are *denied*. A `umask` of `0022` for example does *not* set write permissions for group and others. Set to `0077` to prevent group and others from getting any permissions.

---

You can set the `setgid` on directories to have all files created within inherit their group membership:

```
chmod g+s someDir
```

Some Unixes [support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#setuid_and_setgid_on_directories) the same behavior for `setuid` (`chmod u+s`), but not Linux.

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that there is no dedicated support for what you're asking for. Only the super user can `chown` files to a different user, and setting a default like this has the potential of user mistakes, giving other users permissions without the `root` user realizing.

Comment: Not "always"; e.g. web server user has password that is not known, so there's no way to `su www-data`

Answer (score 20):

There is another way, quite elegant I think. Using install(1)

For example, zabbix-agentd needs a subfolder inside /var/run, but recent distributions are using tmpfs for /var/run, so the directory does not survive reboots.
I solved it by creating a file /etc/sysconfig/zabbix-agentd containing:

```
install -g zabbix -o zabbix -d /var/run/zabbix
```

Comment: Add also `-m 0700` for instance. *The* answer.

Comment: Note that `install` creates the directory **and then** changes the owner/group. So there is a short time where the directory does not have the specified owner/group. In some contexts it can matters.

Comment: This works on Alpine Linux

Comment: This does not seem to apply to parent directories that are created. Is there a way to cover those as well?

Answer (score 5):

On Unix-like systems newly created files and directories are owned by the owner of the process which created them. Standard utilities normally do not have option to change the owner of the created files.

### Variables with UID and GID of the original user

If you run some commands repeatedly, you can use the variables `$SUDO_UID` and `$SUDO_GID` to refer to the user who invoked `sudo`:

```
sudo sh -c "do_something ; chown -R \"\$SUDO_UID:\$SUDO_GID\" files and directories"
```

### Getting the list of created files and directories automatically

If you want to get the list of created (and possibly modified) files and directories automatically you can run your commands under `strace` surveillance which is based on the `ptrace()` syscall:

```
strace -qqfe open,creat,mkdir,link,symlink,mknod -o '|your_processing_of_strace_output' do_something
```

or you can use for example [Installwatch](http://asic-linux.com.mx/~izto/checkinstall/installwatch.html) which is based on the `LD_PRELOAD` mechanism.

### Ideas for further work

Based on the methods mentioned above it is possible to create a tool which would automatically change the owner and possibly access rights of the created/modified files. The use could be as simple as:

```
sudo watch-chown do_something
```